# JQuery making elements draggable and sortable inside div with overflow

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make divs both sortable and draggable inside a div with fixed height. The problem is that I succeed in making the elements either sortable or draggable. But not both.

Here is the implementation of [draggable](https://jsfiddle.net/ahx7urbk/).
If I just add `$('#sortable-list').sortable()` to the code, it does not make the elements sortable.

On the other hand, if I rewrite the code the [following way](https://jsfiddle.net/fkmkefrk/), I run into the issue that sortable is applied to the entire list which leads to the problem that inside the `start` function `$(this)` refers to the entire list, rather than the grabbed element. I spent an entire day playing with this architecture, and now feel completely lost. Any ideas ?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but is this https://jsfiddle.net/fkmkefrk/1/ all you need?

Comment: Wiesion, yes, exactly !!!

Comment: great :) http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start - since you can access the helper, the item, the sender etc. within those handlers, it makes sense that the `this` reference is set to the sortable container itself and all other relations are linked within the `ui` argument.

Comment: Thanks so much. And one last question please :) Is there any method to access the dragged item in the helper function (if I replace `clone` by a customized function)

Comment: Here's the example. Seems like doe not work https://jsfiddle.net/fkmkefrk/1/

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/sortable.js#L1124 - when you pass a function to the `helper` argument, it will be called with `event` as first and `currentItem` as second parameter, so you should be able to work with `function(event, item)` - also it expects a DOM element to be returned.

Comment: You made my day